# SaveChanges in Entity Framework, where all columns are excluded

Tags: entity-framework-4

I want to to run a trigger on the db. This trigger looks in the 'inserted' table for rows to further manipulate.

My question: If I'm using Entity Framework and have excluded *ALL* columns, marked an entity as modified and then call SaveChanges(), will I still end up with a row for that entity (assume 1-1 match between the entity and the db table row) in the inserted table, or will Entity Framework see that no columns are included, and therefore ignore updating the row?